# How To Determine The Difference Between Two Arrays That Contain Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, compare, axios

I have a function that makes an axios call to the database, This Will Then push the results to an empty array i previously have declared. I want to see if there is a difference between the staffId and Id to go ahead and create a new user in the database. The Issue I am having is determining the difference in the arrays.

```
let userBox = []
let newUserBox = []


  checkforNewUser (e) {
  axios.all([
  axios.get('/updateUserList'),
  axios.get('/userInformation')
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((newUsers, currentUsers) => {
  // do something with both responses
  userBox.push(newUsers.data)
  newUserBox.push(currentUsers.data)
  })).then(
    console.log(userBox),
    console.log(newUserBox),
  ).then(//a new call to create a user if the StaffId is not currently an ID in the userbox);


}
```

When Logging the data the responses are as follows:

```
    0: Array(9)
0: {staffID: 1, dept: "Junior Web Developer", email: "manasaN@tpionline.com", name: "manasa", password: "$2y$10$/zYS7OhzwdLOi6Slzc3Rv.aJdy1J6MjnLCN24GmZ3rMHWUS"}
1: {staffID: 2, dept: "Web Developer", email: "juliof@tpionline.net", name: "Julio Fajardo", password: "$2y$10$MphAC8aRY2uzs1ZEduvCqK1/1nd7t0KukEkvGbx5Y4van.Da6"}
2: {staffID: 3, dept: "Fake Title", email: "johnf@tpionline.com", name: "John Fester", password: "$2y$10$/oa/ESQmhhc5WvxrQKoUU.PjdZY5FccilGfCUL5eyeOU5IDSa"}
3: {staffID: 5, dept: "Fake Title", email: "fakeguy@gmail.net", name: "Test", password: "$2y$10$VWnnw5gRTN2absWos04fsOixW6dbFqsFZL8oPiJm"}
4: {staffID: 6, dept: "Conf room", email: "conf2@gmail.com", name: "Conf 1st floor", password: "$2y$10$KAZa1k2Sd/rg6dnVeqw4duB/XbAdze6Zle3ZhcMaRphloG."}
5: {staffID: 8, dept: "Fake Title", email: "newguy@gmail.net", name: "New guy", password: ""}
6: {staffID: 9, dept: "Fake Title", email: "nguy@gmail.net", name: "New Guy2", password: ""}
7: {staffID: 20, dept: "Erwing", email: "erwingh@tpionline.com", name: "Erwing Hernandez", password: "$2y$10$RWgOBbUHojgmyk3behYhd.kzdFEiH.6d70pS5q5Gf3ZYEa"}
8: {staffID: 12, dept: "Conf room", email: "cristinab@tpionline.com", name: "Cristina Bermudez", password: "$2y$10$92I6fSJY6OW001cdaeF5tdHBjWHBmoCvX1RnfhTspjpBa"}


    0: {id: 1, firstName: "Elton", lastName: "Frederick", departmentId: 1, admin: true, …}
1: {id: 2, firstName: "Julio", lastName: "Probando", departmentId: 1, admin: false, …}
2: {id: 3, firstName: "Corey", lastName: "Chris", departmentId: 2, admin: false, …}
3: {id: 4, firstName: "Daisy", lastName: "Ramos", departmentId: 3, admin: false, …}
4: {id: 5, firstName: "Test", lastName: "User", departmentId: 0, admin: false, …}
5: {id: 6, firstName: "Tes2t", lastName: "Use2r", departmentId: 3, admin: false, …}
6: {id: 7, firstName: "Air Car Hotel", lastName: "Nunca", departmentId: 4, admin: false, …}
7: {id: 8, firstName: "Jenn", lastName: "Lee", departmentId: 4, admin: false, …}
8: {id: 9, firstName: "Reyna", lastName: "Pagan", departmentId: 5, admin: false, …}
9: {id: 10, firstName: "Ameilia", lastName: "Rodriguez", departmentId: 6, admin: false, …}
```

If there is no staff ID that matches the ID that means the user is not in the database and needs to be created at some other endpoint. When i try to map the IDS of either and compare them I have issues. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to map the arrays and just get staffId and then compare it to just the ID. If i can do that and determine if a staffID is an ID or not I can figure the rest from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all your ids in an object and loop new users to find different ids.
This way you don't use nested loops which is a plus if you are working with large database.

```js
const userBox = [ {staffID: 1, dept: "Junior Web Developer", email: "manasaN@tpionline.com", name: "manasa", password: "$2y$10$/zYS7OhzwdLOi6Slzc3Rv.aJdy1J6MjnLCN24GmZ3rMHWUS"},
    {staffID: 2, dept: "Web Developer", email: "juliof@tpionline.net", name: "Julio Fajardo", password: "$2y$10$MphAC8aRY2uzs1ZEduvCqK1/1nd7t0KukEkvGbx5Y4van.Da6"},
    {staffID: 3, dept: "Fake Title", email: "johnf@tpionline.com", name: "John Fester", password: "$2y$10$/oa/ESQmhhc5WvxrQKoUU.PjdZY5FccilGfCUL5eyeOU5IDSa"},
    {staffID: 5, dept: "Fake Title", email: "fakeguy@gmail.net", name: "Test", password: "$2y$10$VWnnw5gRTN2absWos04fsOixW6dbFqsFZL8oPiJm"},
    {staffID: 6, dept: "Conf room", email: "conf2@gmail.com", name: "Conf 1st floor", password: "$2y$10$KAZa1k2Sd/rg6dnVeqw4duB/XbAdze6Zle3ZhcMaRphloG."},
    {staffID: 8, dept: "Fake Title", email: "newguy@gmail.net", name: "New guy", password: ""},
    {staffID: 9, dept: "Fake Title", email: "nguy@gmail.net", name: "New Guy2", password: ""},
    {staffID: 20, dept: "Erwing", email: "erwingh@tpionline.com", name: "Erwing Hernandez", password: "$2y$10$RWgOBbUHojgmyk3behYhd.kzdFEiH.6d70pS5q5Gf3ZYEa"},
    {staffID: 12, dept: "Conf room", email: "cristinab@tpionline.com", name: "Cristina Bermudez", password: "$2y$10$92I6fSJY6OW001cdaeF5tdHBjWHBmoCvX1RnfhTspjpBa"} ]


const newUserBox = [ {id: 1, firstName: "Elton", lastName: "Frederick", departmentId: 1, admin: true},
    {id: 2, firstName: "Julio", lastName: "Probando", departmentId: 1, admin: false},
    {id: 3, firstName: "Corey", lastName: "Chris", departmentId: 2, admin: false},
    {id: 4, firstName: "Daisy", lastName: "Ramos", departmentId: 3, admin: false},
    {id: 5, firstName: "Test", lastName: "User", departmentId: 0, admin: false},
    {id: 6, firstName: "Tes2t", lastName: "Use2r", departmentId: 3, admin: false},
    {id: 7, firstName: "Air Car Hotel", lastName: "Nunca", departmentId: 4, admin: false},
    {id: 8, firstName: "Jenn", lastName: "Lee", departmentId: 4, admin: false},
    {id: 9, firstName: "Reyna", lastName: "Pagan", departmentId: 5, admin: false},
    {id: 10, firstName: "Ameilia", lastName: "Rodriguez", departmentId: 6, admin: false}]

let userIds = {};
let newUsers = [];
     
// Save all user Ids in object
for (let user of userBox) {
  userIds[user.staffID] = user.staffID;
}
    
// Compare new users with previous user ids and push new users in an array
for (let newUser of newUserBox) {
  if (!userIds[newUser.id]) {
    newUsers.push(newUser);
  }
}
console.log(newUsers);
```

Comment: My axios call takes some time to return the data, whats a better way to get the same result but waiting for the axios call to return the promise? Both the const are populated from axios request.

Comment: Add `let userBox = []` and `let newUserBox = []` in .then and handle data and checks there. You should use this arrays only inside .then methods to be sure data is fetched.